# Pandas search string for a number and return the char at the end of it?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a column in a pandas dataframe:

```
string_col
541511N~541512N~541513N
332710Y~332999Y
Null
238210Y~423690Y~517911Y~517919Y~532490Y~561421Y~811213Y
```

I am trying to search for certain number and get the Char that is on the end.

For example `541513` in the first row it is `541513N` I am trying to get the `N` at the end.

So, I would like to create a new column that has that information:

So the result would be:

```
string_col    541513_answer
541511N~541512N~541513N    N
332710Y~332999Y    NaN
Null    Nan
238210Y~423690Y~517911Y~517919Y~532490Y~561421Y~811213Y    Nan
```

EDIT:

Search for 'A6' and return next 8 char.

```
string_col2    
A620240328     
A620180614     
Null           
xx     

string_col2   x  
A620240328    20240328
A620180614    20180614
Null          NaN
xx            NaN
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC:

```
In [35]: df['541513_answer'] = df.string_col.str.extract(r'541513(\w+)', expand=True)

In [36]: df
Out[36]:
                                          string_col 541513_answer
0                            541511N~541512N~541513N             N
1                                    332710Y~332999Y           NaN
2                                               Null           NaN
3  238210Y~423690Y~517911Y~517919Y~532490Y~561421...           NaN
```

**UPDATE:**

```
In [6]: df
Out[6]:
  string_col2
0  A620240328
1  A620180614
2        Null
3          xx

In [9]: df['x'] = df['string_col2'].str.extract(r'A6(.{8})', expand=False)

In [10]: df
Out[10]:
  string_col2         x
0  A620240328  20240328
1  A620180614  20180614
2        Null       NaN
3          xx       NaN
```

Comment: Great, also how would I expand that to extract 8 char after a substring?  E.g. `A620240328` I want to search for `A6` and return `20240328`

Comment: @spitfiredd, could you please post a corresponding small input and desired data sets?

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> df['54513_answer'] = df['string_col'].apply(lambda x: x[-1] if len(x)>6 and x[-7:-1]=='541513' else 'Null')
>>> df
                                          string_col 54513_answer
0                            541511N~541512N~541513N            N
1                                    332710Y~332999Y         Null
2                                               Null         Null
3  238210Y~423690Y~517911Y~517919Y~532490Y~561421...         Null
```